# QT 5 QLabel setText() + setStyleSheet() leads to crash

Tags: qt, crash, settext, qlabel

So, wdgt is a pointer to my class, that inherits from QLabel. When I run the following code, application crashes.

```
wdgt->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : red }");
wdgt->setText(indexOfWdgt);
```

If I use only one of this functions, it works, but together they do crash the programm. What could be the reason?

Comment: You should show some code of your class.

Comment: Without seeing more code, we can only guess. For example, what is indexOfWdgt and how is it created? Does wdgt point to an invalid pointer? Where does it crash and have you tried to debug it? What does the call stack show when your program crashes? I could go on and on. Your question is a bit like saying 'I'm thinking of a number, what is it?'. So, please add code for us to examine, so that we can assist.